# dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Permission denied with root user in LXC container after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, container, dmesg

I had an LXC container running in Proxmox with Ubuntu 21.04. In this container `dmesg` worked as expected with a root user.

I used `do-release-upgrade` and successfully upgraded the LXC container to Ubuntu 21.10. After this `dmesg` no longer works with the error `dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Permission denied`. No other changes were made to this container, and this is with the root user.

Is there any way to make this work again?

Comment: There are multiple layers of protection, including but not limited to: cgroups(7)'s devices (/dev/kmsg), seccomp(2), apparmor/selinux. Any of them could have changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have no /dev/kmsg at all, and /var/log/dmesg is totally empty. I don't know what to do to fix this.

Comment: Actually after all this I just realized this is an unprivileged container... so yea this makes sense. Sorry to waste your time.